# Drupal6 - Getting term id from term name

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-taxonomy

Hi
Suppose I have a term name called "product" and the term id is "123", how can I use the term name "product" to get the term id "123"?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$get_term = taxonomy_get_term_by_name('product');

$term_id = $get_term[0]->tid;
```

This should work for you.

Answer (score -1):

use this function

```
taxonomy_get_tid_by_name('product')
```

return value is array .

Comment: Sorry, it not works, I tried taxonomy_get_term_by_name and it works. Reference: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/6

Comment: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/_taxonomy_get_tid_from_term/6

Comment: Krishna, you are right, that would work, but you forgot to preface the function with an underscore: _taxonomy_get_tid_by_name(). The leading underscore, though, makes it a private function, which are best avoided in modules you didn't author. Laxman13's answer is the best practice.